# JSON array not being parsed

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON response in this format:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "categories": [{
        "id": "774",
        "name": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "774",
        "name": "1"
    }]
}
```

And I am parsing it like this:

```
try {
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
 String success =  String.valueOf(obj.getBoolean("success"));

 JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("categories");
 //loop through each object
 for (int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {

   JSONObject jsonProductObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = jsonProductObject.getString("name");
   String url = jsonProductObject.getString("id");
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I only get the value of success. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you are fetching wrong array.
 It should be JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("categories");
 instead of JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("checkouts");

Comment: post your logcat errors

Comment: why you are getting success value in a boolean like this obj.getBoolean("success") its wrong way as json is comming in the form of string  fetch its value like this `String success = obj.getString("success");`

Comment: The key of success is boolean, so i did just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse as below -

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

String success =  obj.getString("success");
JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("categories");
//loop through each object
for (int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jsonProductObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonProductObject.getString("name");
    String url = jsonProductObject.getString("id");

}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

correct json key

JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("checkouts");

replace by:

JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("categories");

Comment: I edited the code, that was my mistake. I'm using categories key now but its the same result.

Comment: hey it should not  be happen as i tested your code its all working..

Answer (score 1):

DO like this,

```
if (!result.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                try {
                JSONObject _jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                boolean json = false;

                    json = _jsonObject.getBoolean("Status");
                    JSONArray jsonArray1 =  _jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");

                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray1.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");

                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Utils.printLoge(5, "error parse json", "--->" + e.getMessage());
                    return "ERROR";
                }
            }
```

Comment: is your peoblem solved ? @Steve Kamau

Comment: Yes it has thank you very much for your help!!